# Webshim: How to set no spinbuttons option statically

Tags: webshim

I tried to remove the spin from a date control:

```
$.webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', 
 {
     replaceUI : true,
     date : 
      {
       nospinbtn : true,
       startView : 2
      }
  });
```

Tried also other variants, but never succeeded.

Is there a documentation? Also for similar cases as to set the 'position' property.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some [config examples for the datepicker](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/webforms/3-webforms-widgets.html#date-cfg). Removing the spin-buttons is simple. You only need CSS:

```
.date-input-buttons .step-controls {
    display: none;
}
```